# How to remove a file that cannot be located

Tags: windows

I'm trying to learn MySQL for a database course in which we use MAMP to set up the server. Everything was fine at first, but a few days ago I couldn't connect to MySQL with MAMP. In trying to solve this I removed both MAMP and MAMP PRO from my PC completely (instead of using the provided uninstaller). As a result I cannot reinstall MAMP as the installer still detects that I installed MAMP earlier and tries to uninstall it. In trying to fix my mistake I found that I still have references (I think they are .exe files) to MAMP and MAMP PRO in the windows apps section (. However when I try to remove them I get an error bar saying:

-) C:/MAMP/unins000.exe

and

-) cannot find file C:/MAMP/unins000.exe.

So I cannot remove said files, meaning that I cannot reinstall MAMP

I tried the MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall and ccleaner first to install MAMP, however this resulted in the same error.

I also found some threads that show how to restore a file's directory through the command line, yet the problem with this is that I cannot find the directory of the remaining MAMP files.

As I'm not really into this field I have no idea of where to look to solve this. I'm however intrigued by this problem I would like to understand how this is possible and how to solve this.

In the end I would like to remove those MAMP references so I can reinstall MAMP.

Or (only if I really can't fix this) someone knows a similar program that works as well or better.

Comment: Windows is thinking that your programs are still installed though you have uninstalled? And you would like to install again?

Comment: Yes that is the case. However it seems I totally missed the delete button in the ccleaner program (I tried to use uninstall) and was able to delete it in this manner. While my problem is actually solved now I would still like to know how it is that windows was thinking the program was still present, yet was not able to delete it because it could not find it.

Comment: That depends on the uninstaller of the program. For eg, after deleting the files, it executed a custom action that threw error and returning to windows installer that the uninstallation has failed, then windows won't think that program has been uninstalled. Can't entire blame windows for this.